# Is creating and assigning values to List<T> thread-safe?

Tags: c#, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a question about the thread-safety of the `List<T>` collection.

Here is my test class:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.a = 100;
t.b = 20;
t.c = 10;
```

Then let's say 10 instance of above have been created and added to the List as below.

```
List<Test> tCollection = new List<Test>();
tCollection.add(t);
```

Later I iterate through the objects of test in `tCollection`.

```
foreach(Test t in tCollection)
{
// do calculation 
}
```

Is adding objects to `List<Test>` and iteration through `List<Test>` is thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default .net collections are **not** thread-safe.
This means that they contain no additional code that deals with multi-threaded access, since such code would decrease their performance in single-thread scenarios.

As Alexander Galkin said in the other answer, Microsoft provides some [collections that are tailor-made for multi-threaded access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However you will note that there is no `ConcurrentList<T>` that works exactly like a List. This is because creating a thread-safe list with with all the properties of a list such as random access, insertion and removal *and* good performance is practically impossible. 
The closest equivalent in your case would be a [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ConcurrentStack<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, there may be an easier way in your case:
**Read-only access** to a List is always thread-safe. You can iterate over your list, or access random elements, from as many threads as you want, provided that you do not change the list.

Adding elements to the list is not thread-safe. This will be obvious if you iterate over the list while adding elements, you will get an Exception: *"Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated"*.

But even adding elements from multiple threads without iterating over the list at the same time is not safe. You will not get such an obvious error, instead it will sometimes work and sometimes not.

If you only add elements once after the program starts, then you can get by with a normal list. Just make sure that no reader threads are started yet while you add elements to the list in a single writer thread. Once you added all elements to the list, you can iterate over it from as many threads as you want.

For more complex scenarios it is usually better to switch to ConcurrentQueue or ConcurrentStack, instead of implementing your own thread-safe methods using `lock`.

Comment: it means , the below is thread safe,  is it ok to change the item's properties t while iterating  .                                                                                                                                 foreach(Test t in tCollection)
{                              
// do calculation 
}

Comment: Changing the properties of the same item from multiple threads may or may not be thread-safe, depending on the item. But in that case it does not matter whether you only have one item or a list of them. You only need to make sure that your item is thread-safe. If you are not sure whether it is thread-safe, it probably is not. In that case you will need to do your own synchronization with `lock`, a thread-safe collection cannot help you there.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **No**.

Usual collections are all **non thread-safe**.

You have to use the *thread-safe analogues of collections**. read more about these collections [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).